# how to create dynamic google map in android

Tags: android, android-maps

i check my logcat file error is the location manage is null

public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity {
    MapView mapView;
    MapController mc;
    GeoPoint p;
    double latPoint, lngPoint;
    LocationManager myManager;

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.zoom);
    View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls();

    zoomLayout.addView(zoomView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    mapView.displayZoomControls(true);

    mc = mapView.getController();
     LocationManager myManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    myManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,new myLocationListener());

    p = new GeoPoint((int) (latPoint * 1E6), (int) (lngPoint * 1E6));

    mc.animateTo(p);
    mc.setZoom(10);

    //---Add a location marker---
```

//        MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
//        List listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
//        listOfOverlays.clear();
//        listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);

```
    mapView.invalidate();

}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

class myLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void ListLocationUpdater() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        if (myManager != null) {
            // List list = myManager.getAllProviders();
            String param = (String) myManager.getProviders(true).get(0);
            loc = myManager.getLastKnownLocation(param);
            if (loc != null) {
                latPoint = loc.getLatitude();
                lngPoint = loc.getLongitude();
                Log.e("RootDrawApplication",String.valueOf(latPoint)+"  , "+String.valueOf(lngPoint));

            } else
                Log.e("GoogleMaps ", "Error: Location  is null");
        } else
            Log.e("GoogleMaps ", "Error: Location Manager is null");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set up a LocationListener ([here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html)). Within the LocationListener's onLocationChanged method, just have your map animate to the updated location.

Comment: i write the code by using  LoationListener but i shows only blue background screen please correct me. i paste my new coding by editing my question. plz...

Comment: i check my logcat file the error is Location manager is null.